# "Se o item "tal" for selecionado da spinner1, então item "tal2" da spinner2 é selecionado" como fazer um if nisso?

Tags: java, android

```
public void Spinner1() {
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.curso_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void Spinner2() {
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.turma_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void Spinner3() {
    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.periodo_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);

    if ("Redes de Computadores".equals(R.array.curso_array)) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Então, to fazendo um pequeno formulário no meu aplicativo android, porém to com problema na parte de Spinner.
Nesse formulário há três Spinners, sendo que é Curso, outro é Periodo e por fim Turma. A condição é: Se o item "Redes" de Curso for selecionado, o item "Tarde" de Turma é automaticamente selecionado.
Em ambas spinners estou usando array.
Espero ter explicado! :D

Comment: Voce explicou a condição para o curso Redes, mas qual é a logica geral que voce usa para determinar o que o segundo e o terceiro spinner devem mostrar baseado no que foi escolhido no primeiro spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você definir o spinner, coloque junto este código para definir um listener que executa toda vez que a seleção muda.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // Aqui você checa se a nova seleção é o curso de redes.
        if (id == ID_DO_CURSO_REDES){
            // se for, definimos a seleção do spinner2 (periodo) para tarde.
            final spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            spinner2.setSelection(ID_DO_PERIODO_TARDE);
        }
    }
    });
```